# Inserting a transparent background image

Tags: includegraphics

I am wanting to include a signature on a document using

```
    Signed:\\
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Signature}
    \rule[1em]{25em}{0.5pt}
```

The image is .png with a transparent background. 
However, no matter what method I have tried (converting to eps, TikZ, plus a few other suggestions here on stackexchange) the image always moves the line away from it. It does the same with text, where the image just moves the text around it.

How can I get it to just insert the image and disregard changing anything else near the image? [H], [h!], floats, transparency and a few others don't fix the issue.

Comment: A graphic is a box and has a size. But you can hide/change its size, e.g. \smash{...}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this worked 100% !! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    \smash{}
```

As recommended by Ulrike Fischer fixed the problem. The image is now able to move freely without interrupting text or the ruled line. It also doesn't interfere with other images.
The transparent background is also preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put "\\" also after the \includegraphics command? The way you did, LaTeX puts the line after the picture.

Comment: Yes I did, it doesn't fix the issue.